# Use for loop to bind multiple text files together from different subfolders in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subdirectory

I have seen this question asked before, but they don't quite help in tackling my problem.

I am looking to bind (`rbind`) multiple text files from 150 sub folders, but I ONLY am interested in 2 different files in each folder. Here are details:

- Main folder called "Folder" which contains 150 subfolders
- In each subfolder, I want to pull out the files that start with 1 and 11. (i.e. 1_HDx1.txt and 11_HDx1.txt) - there are 2 files of these in each folder
- Create a column in the data frame that has the name of the subfolder the files were pulled from.

I know how to do this if all files were in one folder (see directly below), but can I do something similar for a folder of folders??

```
z <- NULL
files <- dir("Folder")
for (file in files) {
  x <- read.csv(file.path("Folder", file), as.is=TRUE)
  x$source <- substring(file, 8, 10) #name of file for the source
 z <- rbind(z, x)]) 
}
```

File structure for first 3 subfolders out of 150:

```
Folder
- WSTNUM_001
  - 1_HDx
  - 2_LDx
  - 3_LD
  - 4_LD
  - 5_ld
  .....
  - 11_Urbanx
  - 12_Urbany
- WSTNUM_002
  - 1_HDx
  - 2_LDx
  - 3_LD
  - 4_LD
  - 5_ld
  .....
  - 11_Urbanx
  - 12_Urbany
- WSTNUM_003
  - 1_HDx
  - 2_LDx
  - 3_LD
  - 4_LD
  - 5_ld
  .....
  - 11_Urbanx
  - 12_Urbany`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this with a sequence of `apply` functions.

Assuming you are starting with the folder full directory as the working directory:

```
Folders <- list.files() # creates a list of all the folders

# Looks in each folder and returns a path to all files starting with 1 or 11.
Paths <- lapply(Folders,function(x){
  F <- list.files(x)
  F <- F[grepl("^(1|11)",F)]
  paste0(x,'/',F)
})
Paths <- unlist(Paths)

# Reads each of the selected files into a list.
Tables <- lapply(Paths, function(Path){
  read.csv(Path, as.is=TRUE)
})

# Rbinds the list together
Data <- do.call(rbind,Tables)
```

Comment: Thanks! The first part works perfectly to pull files with 1 or 11 from each folder. I try to then read each into a list and it does not work as they are text files. I used `read.table` but get an error.

Comment: What is the error? Try just pulling the first Path and copy that into `read.___()` and see if that works. It may give you a more informative error. Without an example of what the files look like I can't troubleshoot that part.

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

Comment: Can you read just one of these files into R? You could also try changing the line to `read.csv(unlist(Path),as.is=T)`. Quick googling of that error makes me think something funny is going on with the path being passed as a list rather than a string.

Comment: but if you could write code that would read a single one of the files in normally, it should work in that line. (With the possible requirement of unlist() in there)

Comment: I see what's going on... there are no headers because the files are from a model. I can pull it in if I say `header=F`. Then it pulls in ONE file, but it still gives me the error when trying to pull in all files with `lapply`

Comment: Okay, I just ran it on one of my directories and it was not doing quite what it should have been. You need to add `unlist(Paths)` in there to get what you want. (See edit) You want Paths to be a vector of strings, not a list of vectors of strings. the unlist function fixes that.

Comment: Thank you for this. Because it is a list, the columns do not have names. Can I convert to a data frame and rename the columns so it knows to bind each table of equal lengths w/ same column name? Without this, rbind does not work....

Comment: I would do that within the lapply function that generates `Tables`. Add names to each dataframe as it is read in. (possibly also a column showing which file it is from).